# Bind datas from several tables to DataGridTextColumn by Entity Framework

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, data-binding, datagrid

After having created my DataBase with Entity Framework, I have created 4 observable Collections containing the 4 tables I have, and a CompositeCollection to regroup'em, like this:

```
class ViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
private BDDInterneEntities _BDDInterneEntities;

public ViewModel()
{
    _BDDInterneEntities = new BDDInterneEntities();
    ResultatCollection = new ObservableCollection<Resultat>(_BDDInterneEntities.Resultat);
    D98EquipementsCollection = new ObservableCollection<D98Equipements>(_BDDInterneEntities.D98Equipements);
    D98DetailsCollection = new ObservableCollection<D98Details>(_BDDInterneEntities.D98Details);
    D675Collection = new ObservableCollection<D675>(_BDDInterneEntities.D675);
    cmpc = new CompositeCollection();

    CollectionContainer cc1 = new CollectionContainer();
    CollectionContainer cc2 = new CollectionContainer();
    CollectionContainer cc3 = new CollectionContainer();
    CollectionContainer cc4 = new CollectionContainer();
    cc1.Collection = ResultatCollection;
    cc2.Collection = D98EquipementsCollection;
    cc3.Collection = D98DetailsCollection;
    cc4.Collection = D675Collection;
    cmpc.Add(cc1);
    cmpc.Add(cc2);
    cmpc.Add(cc3);
    cmpc.Add(cc4);


}
public ObservableCollection<Resultat> ResultatCollection { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<D98Equipements> D98EquipementsCollection { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<D98Details> D98DetailsCollection { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<D675> D675Collection { get; set; }
public CompositeCollection cmpc {get; set; }

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
{
    if(PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }

}
```

}
What I look for is to bind some values of one ObservaleCollection to one DataGridTextColumn, some values of another ObservableCollection to one anotherDataGridTextColumn, etc.

This is the Datagrid, target of the binding:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DonneesBrutes" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=.cmpc}" Margin="10,65,0,0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected">
        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding .Remarque}" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="PMRQ" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=.PMID}" Header="PMID"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="LibellePMRQ" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=.LibelléTOTApres}" Header="Libellé PMRQ"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Ligne" Width="*"     Binding="{Binding Path=.Remarque}" Header="Ligne" IsReadOnly="True"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="OTM" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=.TOTMPMRQ}" Header="OTM"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="TOTM" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=.SiModifie}" Header="TOTM"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="LibelleTOTM" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=.LibelléTOTApres}" Header="Libellé OTM"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="GA" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=.Groupe_D_alerte}" Header="GA"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Discipline" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=.NomTable}" Header="Discipline"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="DisciplineSubstituee" Width="120" Binding="{Binding Path=.NomChamp}" Header="Discipline Substituée"></DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The first DataGridTextColumn is binded from the D98DetailsCollection, the second one is binded from the ResultatCollection, etc. As the following condition : The property TOTMPMRQ which is a common column of each ObservableCollection are equals.

For example, for a TOTMPMRQ like 123456789, I wand to bind the PMRQ value of the D98DetailsCollection in the first DataGridTextColumn where TOTMPMRQ equals 123456789, then bind the libellePMRQ value of the ResultatCollection in the second DataGridTextColumn where TOTMPMRQ still equals 123456789, etc for each DataGridTextColumn to get on one line values from severals ObservableCollections.

My main difficulty is to make this if condition. Currently, the DataGrid only print ObservableCollection after ObservableCollection, and not a combined result.

I hope I'm not too disordered on my explanations, I always can Edit my post if needed, don't hesitate to ask me more, or less...

Thanks in advance for your help.

***EDIT1:***

I have created a class TestCollectionList which inherit of an ObservableCollection called TestCollection, like this:

```
public class TestCollectionList : ObservableCollection<TestCollectionList.TestCollection>
    {
        public TestCollectionList() : base()
        {
            Add( new TestCollection());
        }
        public class TestCollection
        {
            private string pmid;
            private string libellepmrq;
            private string ligne;
            private string otm;
            private string totm;
            private string libelleotm;
            private string ga;
            private string discipline;
            private string disciplinesubstituee;

            public TestCollection(string pmid, string libellepmrq, string ligne, string otm, string totm, string libelleotm, string ga, string discipline, string disciplinesubstituee)
            {
                this.pmid = pmid;
                this.libellepmrq = libellepmrq;
                this.ligne = ligne;
                this.otm = otm;
                this.totm = totm;
                this.libelleotm = libelleotm;
                this.ga = ga;
                this.discipline = discipline;
                this.disciplinesubstituee = disciplinesubstituee;
            }

            public string Pmid
            {
                get { return pmid; }
                set { pmid = value; }
            }
            public string Libellepmrq
            {
                get { return libellepmrq; }
                set { pmid = value; }
            }
            public string Ligne
            {
                get { return ligne; }
                set { pmid = value; }
            }
            public string Otm
            {
                get { return otm; }
                set { pmid = value; }
            }
            public string Totm
            {
                get { return totm; }
                set { pmid = value; }
            }
            public string Libelleotm
            {
                get { return libelleotm; }
                set { pmid = value; }
            }
            public string Ga
            {
                get { return ga; }
                set { pmid = value; }
            }
            public string Discipline
            {
                get { return discipline; }
                set { pmid = value; }
            }
            public string Disciplinesubstituee
            {
                get { return disciplinesubstituee; }
                set { pmid = value; }
            }

        }
    }
```

I have created every properties I want to bind in my DataGridTextColumn and now I want to set them with their values of the differents valus of my DataBase. For example, `pmid` must be equal of the `PMID` property of the ObservableCollection `D98DetailsCollection`, `ga` must be set the `GA` property of the ObservableCollection `ResultatCollection`, etc.

Am I on the good way, Am I definitly wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not create a viewmodel that represents a row as you want to display it then create a collection of those.

Comment: I could working. I'm not that used to bind datas from several tables, but I'll try what you propose, thanks.

Comment: @BenRobinson I'll Edit my post with what I've done and why I did it. Maybe everything I've done is wrong, maybe I'm on the good way